# I'm getting an error runing my app on vscode

Tags: python, flask

I'm new in flask and python and im getting this error when i run the code on VScode:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
\[293 preload-host-spawn-strategy\] Warning: waitpid override ignores groups
```

my code is:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

it run's on the terminal and it works, but not in vs code

i install some dependencies that i miss but still not working

Comment: My guess is that the interpreter used by vscode, and the one you installed flask on, are two separate interpreters.

Comment: As @TheTridentGuy said, you must have two versions of python installed on your computer.  Flask is installed for one of those versions, but not the other.

Comment: ok ok let me see that, thanks